# Change the value of checkbox when checked

Tags: jquery, html, .net, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to **change the value** of checkbox from TRUE to FALSE and vice versa when the checkbox is checked? I can write a JQuery on change event and change the value but was wondering if there is an other way in HTML?

```
<input name="bool_flg" id="bNow_flg" type="checkbox" value="true">
```

Comment: Is the checkbox part of a form and you want to influence the value that is used when that form is submitted?

Comment: What are you trying to do here. The value of your checkbox is `true` so it will bind to a `bool` property. If its checked, then `true` will be submitted, and if its unchecked, then nothing is submitted (because un-checked checkboxes do not submit a value) and your `bool` property will be `false`. What would be the point of changing the `value`.attribute. And why are you not using `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.bool_flg)` to correctly generate your html?

Answer (score 2):

What exactly are you trying to do?  The `checked` property of the checkbox will always correspond to whether or not the input is `checked`.

I have a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/b8trpnwx/2/) that demos this.

If you want the `value` attribute of the checkbox to stay in sync with its `checked` state then see [this](https://jsfiddle.net/b8trpnwx/3/) fiddle.

Basically you want to register an on change event to the checkbox and make its value equal its checked state.

```
$('#bNow_flg').change(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

Comment: I want the value to change. when it is checked

Comment: If you look at my fiddle you can see that the `checked` value **does** change when checked.  If you want the `value` to change then you have to specify that manually in javascript since the `value` attribute is a free-from attribute

Comment: I was wondering, if it is possible without the jquery like in HTML, I am sorry if it is a foolish question. I am already using it in the same way as show in the fiddle.

Comment: Unfortunately no.  The purpose of the `value` attribute is not to determine its checked state.  See the  [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox) for a bit more info.

Comment: Okay that make sense. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want but by default when the checkbox is checked you got a true value then if checkebox isn't checked the value is false.

So you don't need to specify the attribute value on this kind of input.

Answer (score 0):

Is the checkbox part of a form and you want to influence the value that is used when that form is submitted? In this case you have to use two inputs with the same name like this:

```
<input name="bool_flg" type="hidden" value="false" />
<input name="bool_flg" id="bNow_flg" type="checkbox" value="true" />
```

The background is that browsers will not send values for checkboxes which are not checked when a form is submitted. When the checkbox is not checked, the browser will only send the `false` value of the hidden input.
When the checkbox is checked, the browser will send the `true` value of the checkbox overwriting the `false` value of the hidden input.

Asp.net MVC uses the same trick (using a hidden input and a checkbox with the same name) when you use `Html.CheckBoxFor()`.